# Escape multiple dollar signs in an ant variable

Tags: ant, escaping

We have an ant script with the following task:

```
<exec executable="svn">
  <arg line="export ${url} ${path} --username ${svn.username} --password ${svn.password}"/>
</exec>
```

This has worked just fine until one of our users created a password with three dollar signs in it, like "abcdef$$$", at which point ant  things failed miserably.

How can I escape `svn.password` so it can take any value safely?

Answer (score 1):

It may work better if you use separate `arg` elements for each argument rather than one `line`:

```
<exec executable="svn">
  <arg value="export"/>
  <arg value="${url}"/>
  <arg value="${path}"/>
  <arg value="--username"/>
  <arg value="${svn.username}"/>
  <arg value="--password"/>
  <arg value="${svn.password}"/>
</exec>
```